# Turning Object towards given co-ordinate

Tags: java, trigonometry

I currently have an object flying though space, I want to make the object turn towards a given co-ordinate.

For some reason the object is spinning round and round instead of adjusting itself.

My trigganometry is almost non-existent and so far I've been using guess work so basic explanation please :-/

```
public void TurnTowardsDestination(double DestinationX, double DestinationY)
{
    //Current Co-Ordinate of the object.
    double positionX = x; 
    double positionY = y;

            //My failed attempt at understanding atan2.
    float spriteToDestAngle =  (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2((positionX - DestinationX),(positionY - DestinationY)));

            //The Rotate, true is clockwise false anti-clockwise.
    if(spriteToDestAngle > 0.0){
        RotateItem(true);
    }else{
        RotateItem(false);
    }

    Log.w("direction", Integer.toString((int) spriteToDestAngle));
}
```

Could someone point me to the right tutorial on this or at least explain how I would get the object to move in the right direction.

---

I used a fix that works: (For anyone else stuck on this)
From:
http://sinepost.wordpress.com/2012/02/16/theyve-got-atan-you-want-atan2/

```
    int distX = (int) (DestinationX - x);
    int distY = (int) (DestinationY - y);

    double angleRadians = Math.atan2(distY, distX);
    int angleDegrees = (int)Math.toDegrees(angleRadians);

    //setRotation(angleDegrees);
```

Comment: Trying to do any kind of computer graphics without basic knowledge of geometry and trigonometry is going to be extremely unrewarding.  I strongly suggest you learn some!

Comment: Can you suggest some good tutorial sites?

Comment: I'd suggest acquiring e.g. a high-school maths textbook for this, and working through the exercises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a comprehensive article on this [by Neil Brown](http://sinepost.wordpress.com/2012/02/16/theyve-got-atan-you-want-atan2/). Neil is writing in Greenfoot, which is based on Java so it should be quite straight forward to port the example code.

Comment: Thank you for the link I'll go though it.

Comment: That tutorial helped me figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might find [`Line2D.relativeCCW(Point2D)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Line2D.html#relativeCCW%28double,%20double%29) to be very useful in determining whether a point is clockwise or counterclockwise from a given vector.

Comment: "an integer that indicates the position of the specified coordinates with respect to this Line2D". Where does Line2D come from? The X-Y of the item?

Comment: You'd create the Line2D from the point where the object is towards the direction it's facing.

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to point out that your trig here is actually pretty sound, just your logic is incorrect. For example, if your destination is right above the current position, then the spriteToDestAngle will be 90. Even if you are pointing straight at it, your code states it should rotate. You should store the current direction and compare to that.

**EDIT:**

To clarify, you never take into account your current direction. You rotate based solely on position.

Comment: I would still suggest that you try and leverage what Louis Wasserman suggested, as they may have a faster algorithm implemented to solve the clockwise, counter-clockwise problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking into it. I'm not quiet understanding how to implement it yet though.